# Find how many times a character appear in string in C

Tags: c, string, char

I'm trying to find out how many times a character appear in a string.

For example:

```
char * line = "cat file1 | grep c | wc"
```

how can I find the number of times character '|' appear in the string?

I also have another question:

Is there a way to find if a string contain special character?

EX: "netbean&"

Comment: Try the good old ``for (...)`` loop and a counter.

Comment: Try the good old `strstr()`, for example. Read the man pages on those, there's a whole collection of string manipulation functions.

Comment: Traverse string by `char` by `char` and match each char with your desired one. If match then increase counter. Final counter will show you total occurrence of char.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349053/counting-the-number-of-times-a-character-occurs-in-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
int main(){
  const char *str = "cat file1 | grep c | wc";
  int counts[256] = { 0 };
  int i;
  size_t len = strlen(str);
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    counts[(int)(str[i])]++;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    if(counts[i]>0)
    printf("%c occurs %d times.\n", i , counts[i]);
  }

    return 0;
}
```

output :

```
  occurs 6 times.
1 occurs 1 times.
a occurs 1 times.
c occurs 3 times.
e occurs 2 times.
f occurs 1 times.
g occurs 1 times.
i occurs 1 times.
l occurs 1 times.
p occurs 1 times.
r occurs 1 times.
t occurs 1 times.
w occurs 1 times.
| occurs 2 times.
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more terse/succinct way, just as a contrast to the (in my eyes) verbose solutions:

```
size_t count_tokens(const char *str, char token)
{
  size_t count = 0;
  while(*str != '\0')
  {
    count += *str++ == token;
  }
  return count;
}
```

This uses the fact that `==` produces the values `1` or `0`, so we can do away witht the `if` in the inner loop.

Comment: Great answer (size_t and all), but I think it is more idiomatic to use for-loop because iterator is explicit here.

Comment: Well, a cmp is still generated, so it may well be an if.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it.

```
int i;
int count = 0;

int length = strlen(line);

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (line[i] == '|') {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggesting use of `strlen()` once per iteration is of course functionally correct (=it will work) but also *very* non-typical in C.

Comment: My bad, 3am. Time for bed.

Comment: Of course this was an educational purpose, but it is a bad habit to use `int`s instead of `size_t`s for counting and indexing and using strlen() as loop condition, especially when it is known to not change.

Answer (score -2):

```
int c;
char *str = "hello world";
for (c = 0; *str != '\0'; str++)
    if (*str == 'o')
        c++;
```

if you need to compute a number of substring like "netbean&", then follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *str = "hello netbean& world netbean&netbean& ooo netbean&";
    char *t;
    int c;
    for (c = 0; *str != '\0';) {
        if ((t = strstr(str, "netbean&")) != NULL) {
            c++; str = t + 1;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

Comment: Leonardo da Vinci always introduced uncertainty into their drawings to the idiots could not copy it